# PHP isset function returns all options from form

Tags: php, isset

Could someone help me with learning PHP? I'm want to create simply form and after adding 'isset function' is returning all of it.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <form action = "" method = 'POST'>
    <select name = "something">
    <option value = "Monitors">Monitors</option>
    <option value = "Graphics">Graphics</option>
    <option value = "Peripherials">Peripherials</option>
    <option value = "Processors">Processors</option>
    </select>
    <input type = "submit" value = "OK">
    </form>
</div>


<?php


if (isset($_POST["something"]) == "Monitors")
{   
    echo "Monitors <br />";
}

if (isset($_POST["something"]) == "Graphics")
{   
    echo "Graphics <br />";
}

if (isset($_POST["something"]) == "Peripherials")
{   
    echo "Peripherials <br />";
}

if (isset($_POST["something"]) == "Processors")
{   
    echo "Processors <br />";
}

?>


</body>
</html>
```

It returns all 'echo' after selecting one of option in form.
Without using 'isset' is okey but then returns error with 'undefined variable'.
Where i made a mistake?

Comment: `isset()` returns a boolean value so you should not compare that to a string value. Instead wrap that whole section in one `if` statement that checks if a form was posted.

Comment: thanks for quick reply ;)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Reason:-*** Based on [PHP: isset - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

> Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL. FALSE
>   otherwise.

Because of that your `if` condition becomes:-

```
if(true == 'Monitors'){
```

which always  treated as true and every-thing is printing.

***Solution:-***

Change `if` conditions like below:-

```
if(isset($_POST["something"])  &&  $_POST["something"]== "Monitors"){
```

And so-on for others.

***Also your Php code is unnecessary long, make it short like below:-***

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["something"])){   
    echo $_POST["something"]; // add ."<br />" if you needed
  }
?>
```

***So full code need to be:-***

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <form action = "" method = 'POST'>
    <select name = "something">
    <option value = "Monitors">Monitors</option>
    <option value = "Graphics">Graphics</option>
    <option value = "Peripherials">Peripherials</option>
    <option value = "Processors">Processors</option>
    </select>
    <input type = "submit" value = "OK">
    </form>
</div>

<?php
  if (isset($_POST["something"])){   
    echo $_POST["something"]; // add ."<br />" if you needed
  }
?>
```

Comment: @fullje  also you can make your php code very sort. Check my edited answer for that

Answer (score 1):

isset returns boolen values, do this instead; what I have done is check if `$_POST["something"]` is set and `$_POST["something"]` is one of select option values

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <form action = "" method = 'POST'>
    <select name = "something">
    <option value = "Monitors">Monitors</option>
    <option value = "Graphics">Graphics</option>
    <option value = "Peripherials">Peripherials</option>
    <option value = "Processors">Processors</option>
    </select>
    <input type = "submit" value = "OK">
    </form>
</div>


<?php


if (isset($_POST["something"]) && $_POST["something"] == "Monitors")
{   
    echo "Monitors <br />";
}

if (isset($_POST["something"])  && $_POST["something"]  == "Graphics")
{   
    echo "Graphics <br />";
}

if (isset($_POST["something"])  && $_POST["something"]  == "Peripherials")
{   
    echo "Peripherials <br />";
}

if (isset($_POST["something"])  && $_POST["something"]  == "Processors")
{   
    echo "Processors <br />";
}

?>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <form action = "" method = 'POST'>
    <select name = "something">
    <option value = "Monitors">Monitors</option>
    <option value = "Graphics">Graphics</option>
    <option value = "Peripherials">Peripherials</option>
    <option value = "Processors">Processors</option>
    </select>
    <input type = "submit" value = "OK">
    </form>
</div>


<?php

// If you want to only one value then you can use below. it will echo selected option
if (isset($_POST["something"])) {

    echo $_POST["something"];
}


//you can check isset and compare post value.
if (isset($_POST["something"]) && $_POST["something"] == "Monitors")
{   
    echo "Monitors <br />";
}

if (isset($_POST["something"]) && $_POST["something"] == "Graphics")
{   
    echo "Graphics <br />";
}

if (isset($_POST["something"]) && $_POST["something"] == "Peripherials")
{   
    echo "Peripherials <br />";
}

if (isset($_POST["something"]) && $_POST["something"] == "Processors")
{   
    echo "Processors <br />";
}

?>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Switch Statement

```
  <?php

    if(isset($_POST['something'])){
        $var =$_POST["something"];

        switch ($var) {
            case "Monitors":
                echo "Monitors!";
                break;
            case "Graphics":
                echo "Graphics!";
                break;
            case "Peripherials":
                echo "Peripherials";
                break;
            default:
                echo "Your favorite color is neither red, blue, nor green!";
        }
    }


    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `isset` is, as has been stated, a boolean - which can be tested for in a logic operation( ie: if true then ) ~ the switch statement just makes a cleaner job of multiple if/then/else conditions

```
if( isset( $_POST['something'] ) ){
    switch( $_POST['something'] ){
        case 'Monitors':$item='Monitors';break;
        case 'Graphics ':$item='Graphics ';break;
        case 'Peripherials ':$item='Peripherials ';break;
        case 'Processors ':$item='Processors ';break;
    }
    printf('%s<br />', $item);/* use $item somewhere/somehow*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the condition like `if (isset($_POST["something"]) and  $_POST["something"]== "Monitors")`

Because `isset()` return `true` or `false` as return value .
Please find update code as below.

```
<html>
    <body>
    <div id="main">
        <form action = "" method = 'POST'>
        <select name = "something">
        <option value = "Monitors">Monitors</option>
        <option value = "Graphics">Graphics</option>
        <option value = "Peripherials">Peripherials</option>
        <option value = "Processors">Processors</option>
        </select>
        <input type = "submit" value = "OK">
        </form>
    </div>


    <?php


    if (isset($_POST["something"]) and  $_POST["something"]== "Monitors")
    {   
        echo "Monitors <br />";
    }

    if (isset($_POST["something"]) and  $_POST["something"] == "Graphics")
    {   
        echo "Graphics <br />";
    }

    if (isset($_POST["something"]) and  $_POST["something"] == "Peripherials")
    {   
        echo "Peripherials <br />";
    }

    if (isset($_POST["something"]) and  $_POST["something"] == "Processors")
    {   
        echo "Processors <br />";
    }

    ?>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
if (isset($_POST["something"]) && $_POST["something"] == "Monitors")
{   
    echo "Monitors <br />";
}
```